# How to specify a constant request sending rate in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing long SQL SELECT queries. Each can take several minutes.
I want to gradually increase the number of threads, and observe the behavior of the database.

How to set a constant request **sending** rate for each thread in Group? For example, each thread sends 2 requests per minute.

As I can see, Constant Throughput Timer ensures requests completion rate (for example, if I specify "2" in the timer, it will slow down the thread so that 2 requests are **finished** per minute)

[My test plan with Constant Throughput Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C668I.png)

Constant Timer adds a delay after the request **completes** (not after start), which doesn't fit either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking about Open Model, there are few ways to achieve the target rate, but I don't think any one them can config number of request for each thread.

- [Open Model ThreadGroup](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)
- [Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/#Arrivals-Thread-Group)
- [Free-Form Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup/)

Answer (score 0):

[Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) is precise enough on **minute** level, i.e. you will see throughput got applied only for 2nd minute of your test.

There are more precise timers which control the throughput from the very beginning stage of your test:

- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)